# .NET In memory cache speed Parent-Child relationships lookups by ChildId

Tags: .net, caching, lookup, concurrentdictionary

I need to design a fast cache for this particular problem.
I'm receiving this type of object :

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Child> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

A child can exist in many Parents but the Position may differ.
Only caches reads are : get All children in a group, get group name by group Id

> Having this structure, my problem is : How do I store the information to have searching by ChildId to be O(1) or extremely fast?
> Caching the whole structure by **ParentId** is not really an option as this object doesn't really change that often.
> How to avoid storing duplicates ParentId&ParentName for every child?

What I have so far :

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IList<Child> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}


public class ParentChildInfo
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public int ChildPosition { get; set; }

}

public class ChildDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}

public class Cache
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<long, List<ParentChildInfo>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, List<ParentChildInfo>>();


    public void AddOrUpdate(Parent entity)
    {
        //remove previos Items for parentId
        //parent can have more/less children now
        Remove(entity.Id);

        foreach (var item in entity.Items)
        {
            var interestedCacheData = new ParentChildInfo() { ParentId = entity.Id, ParentName = entity.Name, ChildPosition = item.Position };
            _cache.AddOrUpdate(item.Id, new List<ParentChildInfo> { interestedCacheData }, (_, items) =>
            {
                items.Add(interestedCacheData);
                return items;
            });
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(int entityAId)
    {
        var removed = 0;
        var keysToBeRemoved = new List<long>();
        foreach (var item in _cache)
        {
            removed += item.Value.RemoveAll(x => x.ParentId == entityAId);
            if (!item.Value.Any())
            {
                keysToBeRemoved.Add(item.Key);
            }
        }

        //cleanup empty keys
        foreach (var key in keysToBeRemoved)
        {
            _cache.TryRemove(key, out _);
        }

        return removed > 0;
    }

    public IList<ChildDto> GetChildItemsForParentId(int parentId)
    {
        var items = new List<ChildDto>();
        foreach (var pair in _cache)
        {
            items.AddRange(
                pair.Value.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId)
                .Select(x => new ChildDto { Id = pair.Key, Position = x.ChildPosition }));
        }
        return items;
    }

    public ParentChildInfo GetParentById(int parentId)
    {
        // Interested in only ParentName
        return _cache.Values.SelectMany(x => x).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ParentId == parentId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The main purpose of using a dictionnary is to use the `ContainsKey()` and the direct access `[key]`.
You can use the base class structure `Child` & `Parent`, i don't think DTO will be usefull.

```cs
 private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<long, List<ParentChildInfo>> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, Parent>();
    public IEnumerable<Child> GetChildItemsForParentId(int parentId)
    {
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(parentId, out var items) {
            return items;
        }
        return Enumerable.Empty<Child>();
    }
```

Comment: Using `.ContainsKey()` followed by the `[key]` accessor in this manner is both inefficient (since you require twice as many lookups to access an item), and when using a `ConcurrentDictionary<,>` is incorrect (not thread safe), as the key could be removed between the contains check and the item access resulting in an exception. Use `.TryGetValue()` instead.